# Website javascript not running on iphone (safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile-safari

I do not have a specific block of code to post here, my website includes a fair bit of javascript/jquery which works great on android and modern desktop browsers (including Safari). However when I look at the site through an iphone none of the javascript is running.

Site is www.alexchapman.co.uk, I have checked that js is enabled on the iphone and I am not getting any error messages on the phone. The site is a bit slow so I am connecting to the site on the iphone via a wi-fi connection.

My question is where do I begin trying to sort this out. I don't have access to a mac. Is there anything I can run on the iphone similar to firbug or ie dev tools to try to see what's happening here?
I tried the Electronic Mobile Simulator but this shows the site working fine (although I realise this isn't a proper iphone emulation)

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: If you haven't already, and it's possible to do so, I'd test it on more than one phone. That will give you a good indication whether it's a problem with the site or just that particular phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to turn on the [Debug Console](http://browsers.about.com/od/allaboutwebbrowsers/ss/iphonedebugger.htm).  I note the last error I find on your page is "JavaScript: Error: undefined.  JavaScript execution exceeded timeout".

Comment: That is, the *iPhone* Debug Console.

Comment: This was what I was looking for, thank you - although I am now going to open another question to see if anyone knows how to solve this without splitting up my javascript into seperate files again. If JayC's link doesn't work for anyone looking. The instructions to start debug console on iphone are Settings->Safai->Developer(at bottom)->debug console on (God knows why they spread that info over 7 pages)

Answer (score 1):

There's some workarounds to test iPhone. Try one of [this tips](https://codewithchris.com/xcode-for-windows/). You can [rent a mac](https://www.macincloud.com/), use a [virtual machine](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-pro.html), build a [hackintosh](https://hackintosh.com/) or use a [developer tool](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) that has resources to test.

However, just see the website on iPhone is not enough to solve the problem. If you need to debug, there's a way to do it via Chrome Dev Tools. Take a look at [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@nikoloza/how-to-debug-remote-ios-device-using-chrome-devtools-f44d697003a7).

Those resources can help you to discover a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at your site in webkit, and it is complaining about your **viewport meta tag**.  Instead of separating your viewport content parameters with semicolons, use commas.  LIke this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Thanks for looking, I have corrected this for good measure but it isn't the issue as the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

Disable popup blocker if it's enabled under safari settings.

Answer (score -1):

This website does not seem to be designed for browsing on a mobile device. I would recommend having a separate, much simpler website specifically designed for mobile browsing. This way you can tailor your HTML/Javascipt taking into account screen size, touch sensitivity and performance. You can use the same URL and redirect to the appropriate website depending on the browser type (mobile or non-mobile). If you decide to take that route, I would recommend looking into Javascript libraries such as JQuery Mobile.

Comment: I apologize, my answer was meant to be a comment, but as a new user I did not have the option to add a comment to the original post.

Comment: Thank you for your post, as above not answering my question but I have voted your answer up as its good info - I wasn't aware of a jquery mobile library. A seperate mobile site is not within the scope of what I am doing now, but may be something I will look at later on and when I do I will ceratainly be checking out the jquery mobile.